# Spring annotation processing

Tags: java, spring, annotations, code-generation

I want to ask if it is possible to process own annotation and generate own proxy object on Class annotated with @Component and own annotation?
example:

```
@Component @MyAnnotation 
class Clazz{
  void init(){
    // some code here
  }
}
```

I want to generate proxy like this.

```
class ClazzProxy extends Clazz{
  void init(){
    // some new code here
    super.init()
  }
}
```

And after that I want to inject proxy instead of Clazz.
Any suggestion?

I tried to modify code at compile time with AbstractProcessor so I would not need any proxy object and it's seems hard but I know lombok doing it.
If anyone know how to add extra lines to method in compile time I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: So you want some extra code to be called when the `init()` method is called on a `Clazz` object? That's what aspect oriented programming (AOP) is for, which Spring also supports. See the reference documentation: [Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop)

Comment: @Jesper At first I tried to generate code with com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker. Now I will try AOP but idk if it is what I need. Thanks anyway